# Visual Studio 2013 unable to sign in for license

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

After Update 4 I am experiencing the following error message:

[image: screenshot of error message]

I am not even able to sign in to my Microsoft account but it was working ok before the update. Please let me know what I have to do to get it working again.

Comment: You say you already have a Microsoft account and you were signed in before? Because all I can find is: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/08/07/visual-studio-2015-faq/#CommunityEditionTrialExpiry and according to this link all you need to have is an account.

Answer (score 0):

> ### Licensing / Purchase
>
> 1. I signed into the IDE, but it’s still telling me that the trial will expire. What’s going on? **The odds are that the account you signed
>      in with doesn’t have an MSDN subscription or Visual Studio Online
>      subscription associated with it**. Sign in with an account that does and
>      the license should be issued automatically or apply a product key
> 2. Community Edition is telling me my trial has expired. Do I have to pay for Community edition? No, Community edition is free to use. We
>      use the same infrastructure that allows you to unlock VS w/ an online
>      subscription to manage the requirement of signing into Community
>      edition so some of our strings overlap cross these scenarios. Trial
>      here means the period you can use the community edition before you
>      must sign in to fully unlock the IDE.

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2015/08/07/visual-studio-2015-faq/#IDETrialExpiry)

Emphasis is mine. Does your account have a MSDN or Visual Studio Online subscription?

Answer (score -1):

The most common cause is having the system clock out-of-date. Make sure your date and time are set correctly, and sync them online if you have to. This should fix your issue.